# js/vendor/jquery.js returns 404 error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90GYv.png)My jQuery is returning a 404 error. I recently found out the scripts were being called for in the wrong way. It was suggested that I make changes which i did. there is 1 change I can't make or it breaks the theme.  I'm not sure which file controls it though. below are some examples.

header.php - the italicized  `"/></script>` breaks my theme if removed so i had to put it back. I've been told it should be removed

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/cheaptubes/css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/cheaptubes/js/vendor/*"></script>*
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/cheaptubes/style.css" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

footer-home.php

```
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );
?>wp-content/themes/cheaptubes/js/vendor/
    wp_register_script( 'reverie-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
<script>
```

footer.php

```
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/cheaptubes/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/cheaptubes/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).foundation();
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

layout.php top

```
<script src="<?php ech esc_url(home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/cheaptubes/js/vendor/
```

bottom

```
<script src="<wp_register_script('reverie-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), ", true );
```

I've been searching online for good javascript validators w/out much success

Comment: Which request is resulting in a 404 error?  What is the actual client-side code making that request?  What is the URL of the request?  Why do you expect that URL should be correct?

Comment: It is often good practice to share a representation of the error that you are receiving.  How do you know that you're getting a 404 ?  Is it shown in the main of the window, do you find it in the javascript console ?  The errors often contain the answers.

Comment: Thank you.  What is odd now is according to dreamhost it isn't returning a 404 anymore. When I run a scan at screaming frog it tells me I have no 404 errors but i've checked it on 3 computers and my phone and it still there. I took a screen shot of the error and will try to add it into the post

Answer (score 0):

404 means the url is invalid, the file isn't found on the server. The actual url you are looking for is: 
http://cheaptubes.com/wp-content/themes/cheaptubes/js/vendor/jquery.js

I think you should try removing that entire line that you have italicized, I think you're already including the jquery file in the footer.php.

Comment: I did try removing that line and had dreamhost clear the server cache but no luck

Comment: I'm at a loss then.  This tag isn't valid: `<script src="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-content/themes/cheaptubes/js/vendor/*"></script>*`.  The src of a script tag has to point to a specific resource on the server, not just a directory.  I presumed this was attempting to load jquery.js, is it possible there is another script in that directory that you should be loading?

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up consulting a web developer who said the script is meaningless because its already loaded with another script.  Yes it was when loading jquery.js